# How to run Python server without command prompt

Tags: python, django

I'm developing some Python project with Django. When we render the Python/Django application, we need to open the command prompt and type in `python manage.py runserver`. That's ok on for the development server. But for production, it looks funny. Is there anyway to run the Python/Django project without opening the command prompt?

Comment: You wouldn't do that for production - you'd have it running on some kind of cron/supervisor restart and behind a proper server. Have you looked at deployment? http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter12.html or various other resources for instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [deployment section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/) of the documentation details steps to configure servers to run django in production.

`runserver` is to be used strictly for development and should **never** be used in production.

Comment: why should never be used ...? may you explain that?

Answer (score 3):

You run the runserver command only when you develop. After you deploy, the client does not need to run `python manage.py runserver` command. Calling the url will execute the required view. So it need not be a concern

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Linux I wrote a pretty, pretty basic script, which I am always using when I don't want to call this command.

Note: You really just should use the "runserver" for developing :)

```
#!/bin/bash

#Of course change "IP-Address" to your current IP-Address  and the "Port" to your port.
#ifconfig to get your IP-Address

python manage.py runserver IP-Address:Port
```

just name it runserver.sh and execute it like this in your terminal:

```
./runserver.sh
```